Error on installing Virtual Device Manager in Android Studio: /dev/kvm not found
I am trying to install virtual device manager in my newly installed Android Studio, but I'm getting the error Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings, ensure that your Linux distro has working KVM module. when I set up the AVD in Android Studio.
[Pixel Fold API 35 /dev/kvm is not found:


I see no Ubuntu question here sorry.  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  No Ubuntu product/release is mentioned, in fact your question doesn't even mention Ubuntu.  BIOS or uEFI settings are device firmware specific, so even if this was a hardware Q&A site, you provided no hardware details anyway

"Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings, ensure that your Linux distro has working KVM module" please do that ;-) see for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40342015/enable-vt-x-in-your-bios-security-settings-ensure-that-your-linux-distro-has-wo
